# Best practices fetching data from backend api when building frontend

Tags: api, frontend, backend

So i was thinking, what is the best practices when it comes to building front end that need to talk alot to an api backend.
My scenario, iam building frontend with vue that consumes a node, express api as backend. A simple todo app.
Right now i do this.

1. User log in and all todos, categories, and userinfo is fetched and saved in my vuex store
2. if user close page and open it again or reloads the page the vuex store resets ofc so i check if the user is still loggedin then i fetch all data again and save it in my vuex store the same way as i do when a user logging in.
3. user can now browse around the app and no need to call api because the store has all data the frontend needs. this saves a lot of API calls ofc.
4. if user creates a new or edit some todo, category or userinfo i send it to the api and once again fetching all data again like i do when user logging in.

So this way the store always has the correct data. And it works ofc, but iam thinking that it only works good for small applications. So if my user starts adding 10000s of todos and categories it would be a lot of data to fetch and save in the store.

So is the best practice to only fetch data from api when user needs it in the frontend like showing todos or categories but that would also require a lot more api calls?

Comment: only you can decide this, this is way to open, this is not based on something concrete so the answer will vary based on your use case. Its not about best practice its about what makes sense. if only 1 person can interact on their STUFFs then you can cache it locally, depending on amount, but you could cache on usage like fetch as they access. if many users are interact on the same data well then you have syncing issues... so again depends on the use case and how much code you want /need to write.

Comment: We need a little more information. How does 1 users data effect another users data? How imperative is it that the data a user is looking at is real-time? Does a user need ALL of this data immediately when they log in...maybe there is an opportunity to precompute, or show a user a subset of their data, and get the rest as needed. Without knowing more details, it will be hard to get a solid answer for your question.

Comment: Thats some great answers and just what i was looking for. Just needed some second opinions :) .